# WPF Compact this XAML which assigns static string to binding

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding, staticresource, imultivalueconverter

There may not be any practical use of what I want to do, but just to satisfy my curiosity can we compact the 2nd binding in the following XAML into 1 line

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource One}"></Binding>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Source>
                    <sys:String>2</sys:String>
                </Binding.Source>
            </Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

StaticResource One gives me "1" and MyConverter just concatenates all values it gets.
What I am looking for is some way to express the 2nd binding in a compact format like the 1st binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there's some reason you don't want to define a second static resource called `Two` and then use the same syntax as with `One`...

You should be able to:

```
<Binding Source="2"/>
```

Since `Source` is just an `Object`, this should assign the string "2" to the `Source`. Haven't checked though as I'm on linux at the moment.

Comment: Awesome... i knew there had to be something simple